# Find the median of the exponential random variable with parameter λ

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, median

The median of a random variable X is a number µ that satisﬁes

[image]

Find the median of the exponential random variable with parameter λ.

Comment: Hint: write first hte CDF of exponential law...

Comment: Sorry but... what kind of approach did you try, which failed to lead you to the solution?

Answer (score 12):

For any positive number $x$, we have
$$F_X(x)=\Pr(X\le x)=\int_0^x \lambda e^{-\lambda t}\,dt=1-e^{-\lambda x}.$$

So to find the median $m$, we want to solve the equation
$$1-e^{-\lambda m}=\frac{1}{2}$$
for $m$, or equivalently to solve the equation 
$$e^{-\lambda m}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Take the (natural) logarithm of both sides. We get 
$$-\lambda m=\ln(1/2)=-\ln(2).$$
Now solve for $m$. We get
$$m=\frac{\ln 2}{\lambda}.$$

**Remark:** It is unfortunate that in the problem the symbol $\mu$ is used for the **median**, since $\mu$ is a standard name for the **mean**. A common symbol for the median is $m$.

Comment: Maybe the author's intention was to declare the rate as 1/2 and meant to use "λ" rather than "μ".

Comment: @Tommyixi: Sorry, still recovering, will not be able to respond for a few days.